# Android app not appear in the store for some tablets

Tags: android, android-manifest, google-play

What 's happening:
Some devices(tablets) is not compatible with the app.
*Samsung galaxy tab 2, 3, etc..

The requirements in the store are all accepted by devices.

=================================

Is declared in my manifest.xml

```
<uses-sdk
      android : minSdkVersion = " 8 "
      android : targetSdkVersion = " 17 "/>

<supports-screens
        android : anyDensity = "true "
        android : largeScreens = "true "
        android : normalScreens = "true "
        android : smallScreens = "true "
        android : xlargeScreens = " true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

Any reason for this be happening ?

Comment: I have an issue like that, my app won't show in the 7'inch tablet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wonder if this might be the problem:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

Otherwise, think about the features you really require, and try to put as FEW as you really need in your manifest.  The more restrictions you create, the fewer devices will be able to use your app.

Also, check your Play store listing, as you can limit your apps exposure here (ether by specific device, country, language, or other things).